# Random selection from a sub-list to fill an empty sub-list

Tags: python, list

I have two list of lists,

```py
A = [['a'],[],['l'],[]]
B = [['m','n'],['p'],[],['q','r','s']]
```

I needed the output to be

```py
c = [['a'],['p'],['l'],['s']]
```

Whenever there is a empty sublist in A I want to append a random selection from the corresponding sublist from B.

my approach for this is not working

```py
import random

c = [x+random.sample(y,1) for x,y in zip(A,B) if len(x)==0 and len(y)>=1]
```

Comment: Your code only checks for `len(x) == 0`. What do you want to do if `len(x) != 0` ?

Comment: @DeepSpace To diversify the sub-list(my categories). I need one and only one element from each sub-list. So, if len(x) != 0 do nothing.

Comment: This is where your mistake is. You don't want to "do nothing". If `len(x) != 0` you want to take the original list from `A`, as all the answers are doing

Comment: yes, you are right. I got what I am doing wrong...Thanks @DeepSpace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to decide what element to store in your list:

```
from random import choice

[a if a else [choice(b)] for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite the output OP wants

Comment: @DeepSpace why almost?

Comment: Compare the output of your answer and `[['a'],['p'],['l'],['s']]`. Try `[choice(b)]`

Comment: For some reason i kinda like the "a or [choice(b)]" instead of "a if a else [choice(b)]" more, but i guess thats subjective.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `or` operator to fall back to a random selection from `B` using `random.choices`:

```
from random import choices
[a or choices(b) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

Comment: I'd go with `choice(b)`, which is equivalent to `choices(k)` (since it has default value  `k=1`) but more readable

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `if` like this:

```py
import random

A = [['a'],[],['l'],[]]
B = [['m','n'],['p'],[],['q','r','s']]

C = [
    a_sub_list if a_sub_list else [random.choice(b_sub_list)] for a_sub_list, b_sub_list in zip(A,B)
]
print(C)
>>> [['a'], ['p'], ['l'], ['q']]
```